# Texture stretches on faces in Unreal Engine after importing from Blender

Tags: modeling

I've run in to a problem where some of the faces are stretched out in UE4 after importing from blender. The problem starts after I've used the extrude tool on a face in blender.

This is how it looks in Unreal -> https://prnt.sc/que9a8

I was wondering if there is a better way to make a complex figure without extruding faces, because that doesn't seem to work and I've tried adding bunch of cubes together and join them all and it just treats each cube separately.

The figure I'm trying to make -> https://prnt.sc/queaj3

Comment: It seems like a problem of UVs rather than modelling. Does unreal have an option for "clipping" textures ?

Comment: @Gorgious If there is an option for clipping textures I'm not aware of that, I'm pretty new to Blender and Unreal

Comment: in your UV map, do you have vertices on top of eachother, they are trying to use too few pixels for the full length of the face.